# I'm using both Cookie and External(Google) Auth. When I log in with Google, my cookie does not get created. .NET Core MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So as the title says I'm using both Cookies and Google for signin/authentication.

**Startup.cs Cookie Snippet**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
                options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
                options.CookieName = "CUSTOMCOOKIE";
            });
```

**Startup.cs Google Snippet**

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.ClientId = "xx";
    options.ClientSecret = "xx";
}
```

My CUSTOMCOOKIE does not show up when I signin with Google. Basically what I want to do is have the user use Google to sign in to the site, and use the cookie to remember the user for x amount of days.

Is there something I'm missing? I also tried to set 'options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"' to the Cookie snippet and 'options.AuthenticationScheme = "Google"' to the Google snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the SignInScheme of the google options to be the same as the AuthenticationScheme on the main auth cookie like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "CUSTOMCOOKIE";
    options.CookieName = "CUSTOMCOOKIE";
});

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.ClientId = "xx";
    options.ClientSecret = "xx";
    options.SignInScheme = "CUSTOMCOOKIE";
}
```

if that doesn't get you going then you need to show the callback method of your account controller that is used for google callback

Comment: Joe, thanks so much! I was missing the "SignInScheme". This got me the cookie successfully. However, in the ExternalLoginCallback method - in the default code generated with a new .NET Core project - "await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();" returns null. Is this normal behavior when setting a custom sign in scheme? Because even though I have the User and claims obtained from Startup, it isn't showing the user as "logged in".

Comment: I think what they are doing in GetExternalLoginInfo is returning a challengeresult. There is [a demo app here](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit/blob/master/samples/AspNetMvcAuthDemo/Controllers/AccountController.cs) for multi-tenant middleware, but it also happens to have a simple working google auth without identity which may help you. If you are using Identity then you need to set the AuthenticationScheme of the google cookie to be the same as the identityoptions externalcookie or maybe leave authscehem and cookiename unspecified and the defaults will work

Comment: in case you have not found the docs, there is pretty clear instructions here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I should have known Ben Foster would have something up about this. Thank you so much, man. You really helped me out a lot and saved me a ton of hair pulling.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, there is a minor change in the signature of `app.UseCookieAuthentication` and `app.UseGoogleAuthentication` methods in the latest version -

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
    AuthenticationScheme = "CUSTOMCOOKIE",
    CookieName = "CUSTOMCOOKIE",
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Auth/Logout");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
});

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    ClientId = "xx",
    ClientSecret = "xx",
    SignInScheme = "CUSTOMCOOKIE",
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/auth/signin-google")
}
```

Comment: This code does not seem to be working in VS 2017. It doesn't even compile. If I fix compilation errors (like removing PathString wrapping), it does compile but upon Google authentication nothing happens (the same login screen remains). If I click Google again, getting Access Denied page this time.

Comment: Turns out SignInScheme/AuthenticationScheme cannot be arbitrary, it must be "Identity.External". In AccountController, `_signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` internally checks it against this exact value for some reason..